# Store secure files in a folder which requires user approval to access

Tags: filesystems, security

Is there a system, program, or feature in *nix systems which lets a user take a specific folder and secure all access to that folder behind user approval?

I do not mean encryption, since I'm thinking of placing all my ssh-keys/etc in this folder and I simply want to control which applications have access to it while being in the same user (not possible during normal *nix use and the *nix permission model).

I imagined with the tooling around whitelisting applications some major tech companies do (e.g. Google's Santa) that there may have been some work done to secure the access to private files (ssh, openvpn, tokens, etc.) beyond just *nix permissions and that applications can be whitelisted to be allowed access to these files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apparmor. It's a mandatory access control system (MAC) which leverages standard UNIX security, much as SELinux does. In your case Apparmor takes the kudos because it can allow/deny specific applications access (read,write,execute) to files,dirs,pipes and system resources. Plus its learning curve is not that steep as with selinux.